# How do I deserialize JSON.NET objects that don't have names?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How do I deserialize the following in JSON.NET? (I want to use the strings)

```
["String1","String2","String3"]
```

Do my JSON objects necessarily have to look like this?

```
["Name1":"Value1","Name2":"Value2","Name3":"Value3"]
```

Comment: what have you tried on your end.. have you executed a google search or checkout any samples / examples on Json.Net for C#

Comment: I did search, but didn't find anything.

Comment: You get -1 for not researching or trying but your string is pure array. after deserialize it will be come array of string.

Comment: That is a JSON array.  You [de]serialize it as collection of strings.  See http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the following code

```
string[] array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String[]>("[\"String1\",\"String2\",\"String3\"]");
```

Here you have a complete working example

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<String[]>("[\"String1\",\"String2\",\"String3\"]");

        foreach (string item in array)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Is my question that hard to understand?

Comment: No, its not. I'm happy this answered your question :)